# Magento Layer Navigation Starting at Root Category

Tags: magento

Is it possible, with an out of the box Magento installation, to view a layered navigation page that starts from the root category?

That is, using the sample data, if I navigate to

```
http://magento1point7pointzeropoint1.dev/catalog/category/view/id/8
```

I get a listing of all the cell phones in the store, and the layered navigation offers me no option to sort by category.

If I navigate to cell phone's parent category page (Electronics)

```
http://magento1point7pointzeropoint1.dev/catalog/category/view/id/13
```

The layered navigation gives me the option to filter by

```
Cell Phone
Camera
Computer
```

which are all sub-categories of Electronics.

So, what I want to know is, is there a page in the store/system where I can browse to the ROOT category, where the layered navigation would offer me the ability to sort by either the top level categories (Furniture, Electronics, Apparel)  **or** the ability sort by **all* of those parent category's sub-categories (too many to list).

When I attempt to browse to the root category

```
http://magento1point7pointzeropoint1.dev/catalog/category/view/id/3
```

I get a 404 page.  So my first assumption is the functionality doesn't exist, but your first instinct often leads you astray, so I'm turning to StackOverflow/"The Community" for a definitive answer.

(borderline programming related, I know, but I'm asking as part of research a programming problem)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible and in true magento fashion, not all that straight forward. The main thing that prevents the controller from displaying a root category is the `catalog/category` helper.

The category controller's `_initCatagory` calls the `canShow` method:

```
if (!Mage::helper('catalog/category')->canShow($category)) {
    return false;
}
```

Mage Category helper:

```
public function canShow($category)
{
    if (is_int($category)) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category);
    }

    if (!$category->getId()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!$category->isInRootCategoryList()) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

As you can see it checks to make sure the category is not a root category. The way I've approached this issue in the past is to use a module that:

- Creates a custom router to handle the "all products" landing page and instantiate my custom category controller
- Create a controller to handle loading the appropriate site's root category and prov (extends the core category controller)
- Implement my own category helper that only overloads this method and ditches that check

You'll likely run into other issues from there, but at least you should have a starting point.

To answer you question more directly, from my experience it doesn't exist without shoehorning it in.

Comment: Additionally to changing `isInRootCategoryList()` logic, you need use realtime change of `is_anchor` property to 1 for category. However it shouldn't be a value changed in db, you just can set it realtime on `catalog_controller_category_init_after` event.

Comment: @IvanChepurnyi that's another option but could present problems if: you need to continue to use that method as-is, magento might use it on other contexts, you have to overload the resource model (eav and flat).

Comment: I mean under changing `isInRootCategoryList` - your implementation described above. Addition means "additionally to proposed solution". See my info about event and `is_anchor`, don't get confused by `isInRootCategoryList`.

Comment: @IvanChepurnyi ah, I misunderstood, apologies. What's wrong with changing the is_anchor flag in the DB tho? Doesn't the admin let you control this for root anchors? If you wanted to have a layered nav all products page on one site and a standard product listing page another, this would allow for that flexibility.

Comment: @beeplogic The admin does let you change the is_anchor setting on root categories, but there is no form input for setting a url_key.

Answer (score 3):

What I would suggest is somewhat of a different approach, but one that should work without a ton of heavy alterations to the category routing/handling/etc.

Add a category to your root labeled Products, Catalog or something similarly generic. Configure that to support layered navigation and put all your other categories inside of it. This will, of course, mean that the top navigation is messed up; so on to task #2.

Now that the categories are setup as we want them to be, rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` and change out the logic at the very top of the `renderCategoriesMenuHtml` method to start rending with the children of the first `$child` in the loop where it fills the `$activeCategories` array used to build the markup.

This will turn out to be a far cleaner approach than messing with how root categories tie into the hierarchy and it accomplishes the goal of having a master layered navigation. The only potential downside (depending on how you see it) is that you will have '/products/' (or catalog) in your URIs and breadcrumb trail.

Comment: This is how I would try approaching it also. With Magento, it's never a bad idea to look for a solution that changes the least.